# Changing the image displayed at runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, image, xaml

How can I change the image displayed at run-time?

My code is below:

```
<Image Stretch="Uniform" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <Image.Source>
        <BitmapImage x:Name="Profile"
            DecodePixelWidth="300"
            DecodePixelHeight="300"
            UriSource="/MyAssembly;component/Resources/Profile1.png" />
    </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

The images I'm going to use are basically line-art, so using the Image element directly to create this sort of thumbnail is a no-go due to the pixel-resize.

I need to change the image displayed, but changing the `UriSource` doesn't seem to do anything, and if I use the Source of the Image, it seems to ask me to void the whole Image.Source section.

Comment: How do you change the the `UriSource` programmatically? Can you show your changing C# code?

Comment: I found out I can actually pass a BitmapImage to the Source of an Image element.

Comment: public ImageSource FileToImageSource(Uri File, int DecodeSize = 300)
        {
            BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage(File);
            bitmap.DecodePixelWidth = DecodeSize;
            bitmap.Freeze();
            return bitmap;
        }

Answer (score 0):

I think this format for your UriSource may work better.

```
<Image Stretch="Uniform" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <Image.Source>
        <BitmapImage x:Name="Profile"
            DecodePixelWidth="300"
            DecodePixelHeight="300"
            UriSource="pack://application:,,,/MyAssembly;component/Resources/Profile1.png" />
    </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

Comment: I'm still getting an error on the Uri, it does not want to recognize it when I pass it in.

Comment: Did you set the build action of the image to "resource"?

Answer (score 0):

Use a `IValueConverter` to create and return an `ImageSource` from path string. Eg; Your images (desert.jpeg, penguins.jpg) are present in Images folder in your root folder. Make sure, you set `Build Action Type to Content, and Copy To Output Directory to Always` for the images.

```
<local:UriToImgConverter x:Key="UriToImgCnvKey"/>

<Image x:Name="ImgCtrl" Source="{Binding Img, Mode=OneWay,Converter={StaticResource UriToImgCnvKey}}"/>
```

Code:

```
 ImgViewModel vm1 = new ImgViewModel ( ) ; 
 ImgCtrl.DataContext = vm1;
 vm1.Img = "Images/Desert.jpg";
```

ViewModel / Converter Code :

```
    public class ImgViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged
    {    
        string _path ;
        public string Img {

            get { return _path; }
            set { _path = value; OnPropertyChanged("Img"); }        
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };
        public void OnPropertyChanged(string prop)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
        }
    }

    public class UriToImgConverter : IValueConverter
    {

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage(new Uri(value.ToString(), UriKind.Relative));
            BitmapFrame frame = BitmapFrame.Create(img);

            return frame;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You don't need a binding converter to convert from Uri or string to ImageSource. This is already done by the ImageSourceConverter class, which is registered as TypeConverter of class ImageSource. Besides that you better set the Build Action to Resource to embed the image files in the assembly. Thus you won't have any additional, external image files.

Comment: @Clemens Builtin converter needs pack uri. Relative uri wont work.

Comment: And OP uses a Pack URI, so what's your point? Besides that, built-in type conversion works with any valid URI.